# jQuery: Datepickerdate range

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

According to the documentation for the datepicker, the yearRange property determines the range shown in the dropdown (which using the code below is -10 years, +10 years from the currently selected date). Is there a way to change this to 80 years in the past, zero years in the future. Is there something else I need to do to increase the range of dates shown?

```
$('.datePicker, .datePicker').datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(1930,1,1,0,0,0),
  yearRange: '-80+0',
  dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
  showOn: 'both',
  direction: 'left',
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  buttonImage: '/Images/calendar_16.png' });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
yearRange: '-80:+0',
//             ^
```